# Exposing WPF or WinForms application as API or service

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, wcf

I have WPF application and i have to implement it with some other application on same PC.
It is request that my app must be accesed with api or service, and also to hide GUI totaly.
So i need advice on api or service for my application, should i create windows service of WCF application, so other application (JAVA application) can call my app and get returned string.
Any suggestion on this case is more then welcome!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have WPF application, you can host a WCF service within your WPF application. Read for example: [Running a WCF listener in a WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173671/running-a-wcf-listener-in-a-wpf-application)

Comment: WCF can be accesed from JAVA or some other .net application?
case: call api and get string as result back to java application?

Comment: Sure, as @Bond mentioned, BasicHTTPBinding would be suitable for Java.

Comment: As an example i do have a WCF i made a while back that is used by a .Net Winforms app, PHP web page, ASP.Net MVC 3, and ASP Classic

Answer (score 1):

I would do both - a WCF service hosted within a windows service, you can throw away WPF completely.
The WCF's BasicHTTPBinding works well with Java's javax.xml.ws.Service.

Comment: Actually i can't throw away wpf completely :) i still need it.