# How to check if a directory is watched by filesystemwatcher?

Tags: c#, filesystems, filesystemwatcher

I am trying to create a utility method to which I will pass the path of the directory and it will return the instance of `FileSystemWatcher` that is watching that directory (if any). I don't find any helpful resources on the internet. Please provide your thoughts whether it is feasible and if yes how can I achieve the same?

Comment: it should be simple enough to check if a path is  parented by the path - what problems are you having with it?

Comment: @BugFinder I am writing an HA solution whereafter the application restart I want to confirm that all my watchers are up.

Comment: @BugFinder I didn't get your point about "a path is parented by the path". Please elaborate on that/

Comment: each watcher has a path - you can check if that is part of the string you have in hand... so what problems are you having checking they are running?

Comment: @BugFinder The problem is I don't have the watcher instance with me, I just have a path of a directory.

Comment: then you have a design issue

Comment: @BugFinder Its not a design issue. I have my application running which will have hold of the instances. But my recovery module will check actually whether its up or not.

Comment: you are reinventing the wheel of a cluster - if you havent planned how you are to verify these are running - its a design issue

Comment: @BugFinder this is not safe from the recovery point of view. Suppose you have lost the static instance of watcher (in memory watcher) for some reason and if I just check that instance is there or not (to conclude whether watcher is up or not) I might be wrong because physically that watcher sill may be active.

Comment: Quid custodiat ipsos custodes, eh? Instead of starting each watcher individually, you could create a "Control center" that starts/stops/restarts the individual watchers on demand. Use WCF for that and you could use API calls to the control center in order to query the current status of each watcher. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19857052/exposing-wpf-or-winforms-application-as-api-or-service